# How many bits (or bytes) are we subtracting in assembly when using $ - x

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, encoding

This is my source code:

```
SECTION .data
EatMsg: db "Hello Koray",10
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg
SECTION .bss
SECTION .text
global main
main:
    nop
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,EatMsg
    mov edx,EatLen
    int 80H
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80H
```

My question is about this part:

```
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg
```

My understanding is that **EatLen** is a *Label* (a memory address) where the value of $ - x is hold..

But what is - EatMsg here? The String EatMsg consists of 14 characters, but what is the encoding used? If ASCII is used then all characters are 7(or 8?) bits, isn't it? But then how come this works:

```
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg-2
```

for example, in the console I will see:

> Hello Kora

So -2 will actually remove 2 characters but this means what, 14 bits(or 16)? Is every character a byte in Assembly?

But I also tried with characters like "ğğğüüşşüşü" but then again "$-EatMsg-2" again removed number of characters I substracted. I am pretty sure "ğ" can not fit in 8 bits, then how come -1 will remove exactly 1 "ğ" from the String seen in the console?

I hope what I am trying to ask is clear, sorry English is not my mother tongue.

I am working on 32-bit Ubuntu (v12) if any relavent and here is how I create the executable:

```
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/blog$ nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf sandbox.asm
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/blog$ gcc -o sandbox sandbox.o
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~/asm/blog$ gdb sandbox -tui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is the current position in the binary

`EatMessage` here is the address for the corresponding label, so the address of the string `"Hello Koray",10`

Thus, when you write `$-EatMsg` you're computing the difference between the start of that string and where you are now. You're computing the difference between the addresses of EatMsg and EatLen.

And since we're just after the string, that's equal to the length of the string in bytes.

> The String EatMsg consists of 14 characters, but what is the encoding used? If ASCII is used then all characters are 7(or 8?) bits, isn't it?

You wrote 'db "Hello Koray",10', so you're creating a string of bytes.

> So -2 will actually remove 2 characters but this means what, 14 bits(or 16)? Is every character a byte in Assembly?

-2 substracts 2 bytes from the length. Not bits, bytes.
What you're doing is telling the syscall to write 11-2=9 bytes, when your string is still 11 bytes long.
Each character happens to be 1 byte long here (as long as you stick to ASCII), so this will print 2 characters less.

If your string has non-ASCII characters, those will be encoded over multiple bytes.
For example if you write

```
EatMsg: db "Hello Korayğ",10
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg-2
```

This will print `Hello Koray�` because you don't print the last newline, and you don't print the last byte of the ğ, so that last ğ character that you split in half becomes an invalid UTF-8 character.

EDIT: Apparently, not all terminals show the � character, but you can see how string are encoded by looking at the listing file (flag -l of nasm)

Comment: But it also works when I substract like -EatMsg-2 for example. Then exactly 2 Characters will not be printed. Does this mean every character is a byte long and we are actually substracting 2 more bytes?

Comment: Yes. Every character is exactly a byte because you used `db`

Comment: But how can "ğ" fit in a byte? I am not sure just because I used "db" every character is a byte...

Comment: Your string will be encoded in UTF-8, so those characters are going to take more than 1 byte.

Comment: This is what I am saying exactly, then how come -2 still works if it is just subtracting 2 bytes? Again 2 "ğğ" 's will be removed from the string..

Comment: It will not work if you don't remove the right amount! E.g. if your string is `"Hello Korayğ",10` and you remove 2 bytes, it will print `Hello Koray�` because the last character is cut in half, it's not a valid UTF-8 character anymore. Try it.

Comment: @KorayTugay [here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Gvw3jHx.jpg) showing what I described, I'm not sure how it could possibly show a full character for you if the length stops right in the middle. I'm assembling for a 64bit system, but it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: (Note that ü is a valid ASCII character, so it only takes one byte, try with ğ)

Comment: Also note it depends on what editor you use and what your terminal settings are. Given the appropriate code page, non-ascii characters might also be a single byte. Ask for a listing or examine the binary itself to see how the data is really encoded.

Comment: @Jester I checked with gdb hello -tui and when I only have ğ,10 edx will show 3 but when I have something like p,10 it will show 2.

Comment: I shouldn't be answering questions today, I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious. @KorayTugay can you post a listing or gdb's disassembly (including .data)  with the ğ ?

Comment: @KorayTugay [let's go to the chat for a moment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68436/how-many-bits-or-bytes-are-we-subtracting-in-assembly-when-using-x)